# While loop won't exit in Python

Tags: python

The code below shows my try and except statement in a while loop, it works fine in the first part, but for some reason it won't continue on to the next loop, where I ask the user to pick a mathematical operator, and the code starts over at the beginning and repeats the whole process again.

```
while True:
        try:
            num1=float(input("Please enter a value in Number form, with 5 decimal places max"))       
            num2=float(input("And your second value in Number form, with 5 decimal places max"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect, try again")

            while True:
                try:
                    userOp=input("Press 1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication and 4 for Division")
                    break
```

When the code runs, it asks the user to enter a value which works as intended, and after inputting two values the code continues on, but not to the second while loop, but rather to the beginning of the code. How would I "exit" out of the first loop and onto the next?

Comment: The `break` statement in the second loop does just that - breaks out of the innermost loop. Try adding another `break` statement after the inner loop.

Comment: what are you trying to do @Lofi?

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? This code fragment isn't runnable.

Comment: you have to break also the first while loop - just add a `break` at the end, at the same indentation of the 2nd `while` loop (2 tabs).

Comment: Your last `while` loop should probably be de-indented one level. It's at the moment part of the `except` clause, which I presume isn't what you meant.

Comment: Why does anyone want to close this Q?  Yes, it's badly formatted, but that's all.  Otherwise it's a (more or less) working example, along with a description of desired and observed behavior.  That's more than we often get, and it's enough to be a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

this will solve your problem

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Please enter a value in Number form, with 5 decimal places max"))       
        num2 = float(input("And your second value in Number form, with 5 decimal places max"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect, try again")

while True:
    try:
        userOp = int(input("Press 1 for Addition, 2 for Subtraction, 3 for Multiplication and 4 for Division"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Try again')
```